# Окраска таблицы C#

Tags: c#

проблема такая: есть таблица, в которой выделяются цветом строки, значение которых (по одному столбцу больше чем указанное в textBox)... если я допустим введу значение 5, то окрасится скажем 3 строчки, а если сюда же ввести потом 6, то строк должно быть меньше...как поставить очистку цвета?

Код такой:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int st = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

                if (int.Parse(DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) > st)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {     
                        DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                        DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

отслеживайте событие [TextChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) у textBox2:

```
textBox2.TextChange+= (s,e)=>{

    //вернуть дефолтный цвет у всей таблицы:
    ...
    //пересчитать и окрасить снова:

    for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
         int st = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

         if (int.Parse(DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) > st)
         {
              for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
              {     
                   DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                   DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightGreen;
              }
         }
    }
}
```